# How do I add consecutive number together from 1-10

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

Say I want to print out the numbers 1...10, ...easy enough...

```
var i = 1

for i in (1...10) {
    print(i)
}
```

How do I add these numbers together?

Comment: what do you mean by 'add' ? sum of all integers or concatenation of the strings ?

Comment: In is totally unclear what you are asking. If you just need an array with your elements `let array = Array(1...10)` otherwise edit your question and clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Math is always faster than code:

```
let n = 10
print( n*(n+1)/2 )
```

Comment: `n * (n + 1) / 2`

Comment: oops, typs hat too fast... my bad

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the sum of integers from 1 to 10, you can do this:

```
var sum = 0
for i in 1...10 {
    sum += i
}
print(sum)
```

This will output 55 as this adds numbers from 1 to 10 (including 10).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer...god that seemed easy, lol appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can do so with reduce

```
let numbers = [Int](1..10)
let total = numbers.reduce(0, +)
```

This will add the numbers in range [1, 10]

Output of total will be 55

Comment: Since the question asks how to add 1...10, why use 0..<10 ?

Comment: Why? That just add 1 through 9.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I just simply did (1...10) so it includes 10, no biggie.  I'm realizing with coding that there are multiples ways to solve a problem, awesome answer!